# Cannot run android ui tests from command line

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I have created a simple ui test for an android application following this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

Now I have build my project and uploaded the `TestProject.jar` file into a virtual device using:

```
adb push <path_to_output_jar>/TestProject.jar /data/local/tmp/
```

but when I run the command to run my test

> adb shell uiautomator runtest TestProject.jar -c
>   com.uia.example.my.Test

I get this error

> Error: /data/local/tmp/TestProject.jar does not exist

Why? The jar is uploaded to virtual device. Am I missing something here?

---

Also, using a real device I cannot even upload it:

> uiautomator: permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you confirm whether the `adb push` actually transfers the file correctly? There are a couple of ways to check this:

1. Check the output of the `adb push` command e.g. `adb push bin/UIAutomatorExample.jar /data/local/tmp/` In my case the output is `1011 KB/s (5854 bytes in 0.005s)` (the evidence is the number of bytes transferred. Here we know *something* was sucessfully transferred *somewhere*).
2. Use `adb shell` to check the file is available in the expected location: `adb shell ls -l /data/local/tmp/*.jar` Here is the output for my example 
   `-rw-rw-rw- shell    shell        5854 2013-04-11 01:36 UIAutomatorExample.jar` Note: the file size in bytes matched the figure from the first command output, 5854 bytes.

Once we know the jar file has been successfully deployed to the correct location the run command should work, provided the target device is running version 16 or later of Android APIs. (although in practice 17 is the first version of Android where UIAutomator seems to work reliably.)

`adb shell uiautomator runtest LaunchSettings.jar -c com.uia.example.my.LaunchSettings`

Of course you need to replace `LaunchSettings.jar` with `TestProject.jar` :)

Comment: You were right. It was a misspelling. I was uploaded it to `/data/Local/temp` instead of `tmp` :). Now the jar is found but still the report I get is: `OK (0 tests)`. Shouldn't it inform me about the tests executed and shouldn't I see them running in the emulator?

Comment: Well there are several ways to get 0 tests as an output... :) Can you add your test code somewhere, possibly a new question? and I'll see if I can diagnose what's going wrong.

Comment: I added a new question here: [Android tests are not executed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971426/android-tests-are-not-executed)